# Trackbacks not displaying

Tags: theme-development, comments

I'm building a new theme and I'm just working through the [Theme Unit Test](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) requirements in the Codex.  I'm stuck on the Many Trackbacks test.  My theme doesn't show any Trackbacks but for the test post but when I switch to Twenty Eleven they appear.  The comment count is correct.

Here's what I have in comments.php:

```
<?php $comment_list_args = array('style' => 'div'); ?>
<div class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments($comment_list_args); ?>
</div>
<?php $comments_args = array(
            'title_reply' => __('<h4>Leave a Comment</h4>', 'mytheme'),
            'comment_notes_after' => '',
            'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x('Comment', 'noun', 'mytheme') . '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
            'style' => 'div',
        ); ?>
<div class="commentform">
    <?php comment_form($comments_args); ?>
</div>
<?php $pagination_args = array(
            'prev_text' => __('&lsaquo; Older', 'mytheme'), 
            'next_text' => __('Newer &rsaquo;', 'mytheme')
        ); ?>
<div class="pagination">
    <?php paginate_comments_links($pagination_args); ?>
</div>
```

I've tried adding `'type' => 'all'` to the arguments for `wp_list_comments` but I get the same result.

All help much appreciated!